# InnerText returns empty for a specific td class

Tags: vba

I am trying to retrieve Molecular Weight value "448.39" from this [website](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembl/compound_report_card/CHEMBL1112/)

using the following VBA

```
    Dim request As Object
Dim response As String
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim website As String
Dim MWT As Variant

website = "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembl/compound_report_card/CHEMBL1112/"
Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
request.Open "GET", website, False
request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
request.send
response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)
html.body.innerHTML = response
MWT = html.getElementById("Bck-FULLMWT").innerText
    For Each CCv In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
        Select Case CCv.Title
            Case "Molecular wt"
                CCv.Range.Text = MWT
            Case "Molecular formula"
                CCv.Range.Text = "Type"
        End Select
    Next CCv

End Sub
```

which always return empty
How can I get the class value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove any additional library dependencies and simply use split, on response, to extract that info from HEAD. This is quicker than using additional libraries.

```
Public Sub GetWeight()
    Dim xhr As Object, molecularWeight As String

    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    With xhr
        .Open "GET", "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembl/compound_report_card/CHEMBL1112/", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        molecularWeight = Split(Split(.responseText, "Molecular Weight: ")(1), ",")(0)
    End With
    Debug.Print molecularWeight
End Sub
```

Comment: thanx, its worked fine, will complete the code and give you a feedback

Comment: now am trying to get AlogP in the Calculated Properties with the same method but it return wrong data ?? can you please explain why !

Answer (score 0):

The information you want is in JSON format in a `<script>` block on the requested page:

```js
<SCRIPT id=JSON_LD type=application/ld+json>
 {
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "MolecularEntity",
  "identifier": "CHEMBL1112",
  "url": "http://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembl/compound_report_card/CHEMBL1112/",
  "name": "ARIPIPRAZOLE",
  "alternateName": [
    "Abilify maintena kit",
    "OPC-31",
    "OPC-14597",
    "Aripiprazole",
    "Abilify maintena",
    "Abilify mycite kit",
    "Abilify"
  ],
  "image": "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembl/api/data/image/CHEMBL1112.svg",
  "molecularFormula": "C23H27Cl2N3O2",
  "molecularWeight": 448.39,
  "monoisotopicMolecularWeight": 447.148,
  "inChI": "InChI=1S/C23H27Cl2N3O2/c24-19-4-3-5-21(23(19)25)28-13-11-27(12-14-28)10-1-2-15-30-18-8-6-17-7-9-22(29)26-20(17)16-18/h3-6,8,16H,1-2,7,9-15H2,(H,26,29)",
  "inChIKey": "CEUORZQYGODEFX-UHFFFAOYSA-N",
  "smiles": [
    "O=C1CCc2ccc(OCCCCN3CCN(c4cccc(Cl)c4Cl)CC3)cc2N1"
  ],
//etc....
//etc....
```

So you can use something like this (using https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON for parsing the json)

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim request As Object
    Dim response As String, json As Object
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim website As String
    Dim MWT As Variant, blk
    
    website = "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembl/compound_report_card/CHEMBL1112/"
    Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    request.Open "GET", website, False
    request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
    request.send
    
    response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    html.body.innerHTML = response
    
    Set blk = html.getElementbyId("JSON_LD")
    
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(blk.innerHTML)
    
    Debug.Print json("molecularWeight")
    Debug.Print json("inChI")
    
End Sub
```

Comment: thnx for your response. unfortunately github script return error :(, is there a way to make the code wait for the html page to be in the ready state then return the required value?

Comment: "github script return error" doesn't tell us anything much about the exact problem...  That library I linked is pretty much a "standard" method for parsing json in VBA and works fine, so maybe you missed a step in the setup?

Comment: tried same script many times but no luck :( i just want to get some data from that web page and add it to word document content control using a command button, could you help me with a working code please, "i think the problem is that the code run faster than the jave script and get the data before page loading when i download the page and run the code from the saved page it works fine"