# JSON and getElementByID return nothing

Tags: vba

am trying to get data from this [web page](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembl/compound_report_card/CHEMBL1112/) to fill a word form using the following vba code

```
    Private Sub Update_Click()

Dim CCv As ContentControl
Dim request As Object
Dim response As String
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim website As String
Dim LGP As Variant


website = "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembl/compound_report_card/CHEMBL1112/"
Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
request.Open "GET", website, False
request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
request.send
response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)
html.body.innerHTML = response

    LGP = html.getElementById("Bck-CalcCompProp-ALogP").innerText

   For Each CCv In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
        Select Case CCv.Title
            Case "LogP"
                CCv.Range.Text = LGP
            Case "Hydrogen bonding"
                CCv.Range.Text = ""
            Case "Dipole interactions"
                CCv.Range.Text = ""
        End Select
    Next CCv
End Sub
```

the element data always return nothing, only if i downloaded the page that i can return the data, and i have no luck trying to parse json
could any on pls help to write a working code

Comment: The contents of this page are populated after the initial page load.  If you examine the source you can see that the element you're looking for has no content: `<span id='Bck-CalcCompProp-ALogP' class="right teal-text"> <!-- Backbone --></span>`  If you use XMLHTTP then there's no post-load processing to fill in that field.

Comment: There's also an API which you could consider looking at: https://www.ebi.ac.uk/services/chemical-biology

Comment: This site uses an internal API to fetch data. You can do a GET at `https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembl/interface_api/es_proxy/es_data/get_es_document/chembl_molecule/CHEMBL1112`. This contains JSON with the properties you are after

Comment: If you're having problems with the VBA-JSON approach I posted previously - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67437382/innertext-returns-empty-for-a-specific-td-class - maybe you can provide more details around that.

Comment: Thnx Tim, that was very helpful will explore the API

Comment: this link https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembl/interface_api/es_proxy/es_data/get_es_document/chembl_molecule/CHEMBL1112 worked fine, manythanks

Comment: could you please explain how do you followed it ??

Comment: am trying to use same method with other page

Comment: "could you please explain how do you followed it" - I'm not sure what you're asking here.  FYI if you Tag a comment with @TimWilliams (or other username) then the tagged user will get notified, otherwise they may not see your comment.

Comment: @TimWilliams thnx again man, i mean how do you get that address for API data, sorry if that is a trivial question . but i need to do the same method using another web site

Comment: Sounds like a question for @RyanWildry

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question. If your question is how I found that URL, then, I reviewed the web traffic to find this information. I noticed on the page there is a button to pop out content to either embed content, or just view that section. This simplified the problem quite a bit, as there wasn't as many requests to review. You can see the web requests usually in the Network Tab in the dev tools of a web browser of your choice.

Comment: Sorry but another question, the website convert the searched name in the search tab to an ID, is there a way to get that ID from the exact search name using VBA @RyanWildry

Comment: This sounds like a new question, feel free to post it. Short answer use `getElementByID`, lots of examples around.

Comment: thnx @RyanWildry but i mean the ID in the address for searched item i.e. CHEMBL1112 for Aripiprazole

Comment: It's in the webrequest.

Comment: @RyanWildry i need to automate the web web request using searched item